# How to write code to crop image before OCR

Tags: tesseract

I'm trying to write a function to allow user select file, crop image and pass to tesseract.js
I hope someone can write some code to help me achieve the following function: the user selects an image from their computer or camera, phone library, and the screen will switch to the image cropping frame. The size of this crop frame can be adjusted, and when the user presses "crop", the image will be cropped and passed into Tesseract.

Thank you very much!

```
function processImage() {
    // get image
    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.type = 'file';

    var getImage = new Promise((resolve) => {
        inputElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            var file = event.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function() {
                    resolve(img);
                }
                img.src = event.target.result;
            }
        });
        inputElement.click();
    });

**// Please help me to write addional code here**

       // Tesseract.js and OCR cropped image
        Tesseract.recognize(
            croppedImageData,
            selectedlang
        ).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
            // put results to the textarea
            var resultTextArea = document.getElementById('message');
            resultTextArea.value = text;
        });
```